# adding image in layout_gravity but doesn't work

Tags: android, layout-gravity

I wanna put my logo to my app and **layout_gravity** doesn't work, neither found in Android Studio why? maybe there is another option for this, maybe by version i don't know, below I share the code in XMl.

```
<ImageView
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:layout_width="140dp"
   android:layout_height="140dp"
   android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Comment: How does your whole xml look like?

Comment: Did you try just `android:gravity `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using parent layout `<RelativeLayout>` and try `android:centerInParent="true"` or `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` (center vertical) , `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` (center horizontal) in `<ImageView>`
and if you use parent layout `<LinearLayout>` try `android:layout_gravity="center"`